# Is it possible to develop html5 app without using phonegap?

Tags: android, iphone, html, cordova

I want to develop a html5 app for android and iphone without using phonegap. 
Is it possible?? 
If yes please tell me.

Comment: _crossplatform mobile app_ you mean ?

Comment: `**Firefox OS**` coming soon, which is based on HTML5. Which is crossplatform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you want to create a native HTML5 app (ofcourse you can create mobile webapp with HTML5 and without using PhoneGap)

Other alternatives to Phonegap are:

1. Senchatouch [http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/]
2. Titanium [http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2012/05/comparing-titanium-and-phonegap.html]

Comment: Sencha Touch is not actually an alternative to Phonegap.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, but keep in mind that Phonegap grants you access to the device's hardware (compass, camera, GPS), which is not possible in a regular web app. Phonegap lets you create a native app with a a HTML5 UI instead of 'just' a web app.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Both platforms support standard web applications.

If you want to write a native application that uses HTML5 technologies then you will need to wrap them in native code. Phonegap just provides you with some code that does that, you can write your own versions (or use a different prewritten library) if you like.

Comment: Can you provide some reference links or example that can launch a html5 page as android app.

Comment: I said "Standard web application". Open browser. Visit http://gmail.com/ . If you want to wrap it in native code, then I don't know of a guide to writing your own alternative to PhoneGap. I assume you would start by [embedding a WebView](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-embed-a-webview-with-the-webkit-engine/)

Answer (score 0):

[Senchatouch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/), infact requires Phonegap to convert it to native application like Android and IOS

You can use powerfull technology which uses jQueryMobile, which is in the technology field from long time. - [Kendo UI](http://www.kendoui.com/)

Comment: JQueryMobile is slow and heavy.

Comment: @GolezTrol I agree it is heavy, but we can try to make it as light a possible by download-builder... Anyways which UI framework will you prefer along with phonegap?

Comment: I've found JQuery mobile to not be as optimized for mobile platforms as it should be, although they seem to be catching up. But to be fair, I don't know of a better one that offers the same easy and flexibility.

Comment: It's little heavier than Senchatouch but no other framework supports the range of different devices JQM supports and no other framework is mark-up driven!